# Turn on only one switch at a time inside ListView

Tags: listview, mvvm, binding, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement a functionality in which if I turn on any switch in ListView other switches should get turned off.

Following is my XAML:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AllProfiles}" HasUnevenRows="True" SeparatorVisibility="None" RowHeight="-1">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="#F6F6F6">
                    <Frame Padding="2" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" Margin="10,5,10,5">
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" Padding="20">
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#FF6D9D" FontSize="25"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Email}" TextColor="#B1B1B1" FontSize="18"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Switch HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" IsToggled="{Binding IsActive}">
                            </Switch>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I am using MVVM bindings and trying to alter data on event 'OnPropertyChanged("IsActive")' but unable to implement.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

**Edit:**

```
public class SetProfileViewModel:ViewModelBase
{        
    private ObservableCollection<Profile> _allProfiles = new ObservableCollection<Profile>();  

    public ObservableCollection<Profile> AllProfiles
    {
        get { return _allProfiles; }
        set
        {
            _allProfiles = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("AllProfiles");
        }
    }
}

public class Profile:ViewModelBase
{
    private string _name;
    private string _email;
    private bool _isActive;
    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }
    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Email");
        }
    }
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return _isActive; }
        set
        {

            _isActive = value;                
            OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
            //How can I change 'AllProfiles' data from here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are working with data-binding, you should just iterate over the items in your `AllProfiles` collection and set the property to false.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis.. Thanks for the response. I have made changes. Please refer to edit. I am trying to change item data of 'AllProfiles' in 'IsActive' under Profile class. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `AllProfiles` from the property setter in `ProfileItem` you would need to add a reference from `ProfileItem` to the ViewModel which is not a good idea in terms of separation of concerns. My suggestion is to let the ViewModel handle the changes of the active profile.

To do this, you need to subscribe the ViewModel to `PropertyChanged` of each item and handle the changes of `IsActive` accordingly. This is a bit of pain, as you need to subscribe to each item initially, unsubscribe if a `ProfileItem` is removed and subscribe to new items which get added after initialization of the VM.

However, this kind of boilerplate stuff is common for MVVM from my experience. The general pattern is:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _handleItemChanges = true;

    public ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> Items { get; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>();
        Items.CollectionChanged += ItemsChanged;        
    }

    public void ItemsChanged(object s, CollectionChangedEventArgs a)
    {
        if (a.NewItems != null)
            foreach(var i in a.NewItems.OfType<ItemViewModel>)
                Register(i);

        // Handle old items accordingly with Release(i)
        // Handle collection reset
    }

    public void Register(ItemViewModel i)
    {
        i.PropertyChanged += ItemChanged;
    }

    public void Release(ItemViewModel i)
    {
        i.PropertyChanged -= ItemChanged;
    }

    private void ItemChanged(object s, PropertyChangedEventArgs a)
    {
        if (!_handleItemChanges) return;
        _handleItemChanges = false;

        if (a.PropertyName == "IsActive")
             // Handle the change

        _handleItemChanges = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marc.. your solution worked. But, I am facing a roadblock here. Every-time I change property value inside the 'ItemChanged' function, it gets called again and again depending on number of values changed. I tried releasing before changing and then register, but same result. Please suggest any workaround.

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal I usually avoid these kind of loops with a flag variable which activates/deactivates the handling. I've updated the code in my answer. Hope this helps.